# How to pick based on highest value under JSON Object keys

Tags: jquery

I have the following JSON.

I am trying to get the video file of highest resolution:

```
var obj = {
    "videos": {
        "240p": "sdasdada",
        "360p": "sdasda"
    }
}
```

I have started as below, but couldn't able to get the video file of highest resolution:

```
var keys = [];
for(var k in obj.videos){
    keys.push(k);
}
alert("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se9YS/54/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are wasting their time trimming out the last character: [parseInt does it for you automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2833487/34806).  Also the following stores not just the current highest resolution as you loop, but *also* the actual key with the trailing "p" (or whatever it may happen to be: "px" if the OP changes it to this for instance).  This allows the value to be easily retrieved as per my final console line.

```
var obj = {
    "videos": {
        "240p": "https://api-files.sproutvideo.com/file/189ad9b61b1de2c390/2a48ac520d6cfa75/240.mp4",
        "360p": "https://api-files.sproutvideo.com/file/189ad9b61b1de2c390/2a48ac520d6cfa75/360.mp4"
    }
}

var highestResolution = {
    i: 0,
    k: undefined
};
var parseIntK;

for (k in obj.videos) {
    parseIntK = parseInt(k); //will drop trailing character(s)   
    highestResolution.i = Math.max(highestResolution.i, parseIntK);

    if (parseIntK === highestResolution.i) {
        highestResolution.k = k;
    }
}

console.log(obj.videos[highestResolution.k]);
// https://api-files.sproutvideo.com/file/189ad9b61b1de2c390/2a48ac520d6cfa75/360.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var highest = 0;
var out = '';
for(var k in obj.videos) {
    keys.push(k);
    if (parseFloat(k.replace("p","")) > highest) { //convert to a number and compare it to the previous highest number
        highest = parseFloat(k.replace("p","")); // save new highest number
        out = k; //save highest key
    }
}
var HQ = obj.videos[out];
alert (`Highest quality availabe: ${HQ}`);
alert("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
var obj = {
   "videos": {
      "240p": ".../240.mp4",
      "360p": ".../360.mp4"
   }
}

var keys = [];
for (var k in obj.videos)
   keys.push(k.slice(0, -1));
console.log("Max: " + Math.max.apply(Math, keys));
```

`keys.push(k.slice(0, -1))` lets you to select a string `k`, except its last character (in your case, "p"). Finally, `Math.max.apply(Math, keys)` gives us the highest value in the `keys` array.

Comment: You are returning the highest value in the keys array *without* the trailing p.  What do you do then, add the trailing "p" back on in order to actually get the value?

Comment: Sure you can, it's just a single line of code to add the `p` at the end of the number

Comment: Unless he starts using "px".  Hard coding this value is a bad idea IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar approach to another answer, except I don't trim out the last character, and I use regex instead.

What I've done is used the `.match` function to extract only the first set of  numbers that occur in the key. This returns back an array. You can read more about the match function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```
  resolution=k.match("[0-9]*");
```

Then, I insert only the first element of the array

```
 keys.push(parseInt(resolution[0]));
```

You can find the max using:

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,keys));
```

You can find the link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/120pacq7/)